# Use Case statement inside if else block in mysql triggers

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am new to the mysql triggers.
Let assume if i have a table name **teachers** contains

```
teacher_id,
teacher_name,
description,
student_id,
class,
student_year
```

I want to create a AFTER INSERT and AFTER UPDATE  triggers on teachers table.
for that i have a table name called **teacherslogs** with id,teacher_id,student_year,class,student_id columns

so whenever record insert into **teachers** table it should insert into **teacherslogs**.(for this trigger able to write)

But for after update trigger facing issue.

**Requirement**:

whenever **student_id** changed in **teachers** table we need to insert a record into **teacherslogs** with along another columns changes in the teachers table for that record
 for this i have written like this

```
  IF ((NEW.student_id <=> OLD.student_id) = 0) Then
    select student_id,class,student_year into student_id_,class_,year_ from `employees`.`teachers` where teacher_id = OLD.teacher_id;
    Insert into `employees`.`teacherlogs`(teacher_id,student_year,class,student_id) values (OLD.teacher_id,year_,class_,student_id_);
    END IF;
```

But whenever changes in other columns like class,student_year we need to update the **teacherslogs** table for that record where teacher_id and student_id

**Final Trigger Query**

```
create trigger `updateteacherlogs`
AFTER UPDATE ON `employees`.`teacher` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    DECLARE teacher_id_ int(11);
    Declare student_id_ int(11);
    Declare class_ varchar(150);
    Declare year_ int(11);
    Declare dummy tinyint;

    IF ((NEW.student_id <=> OLD.student_id) = 0) Then
    select student_id,class,student_year into student_id_,class_,year_ from `employees`.`teachers` where teacher_id = OLD.teacher_id;
    Insert into `employees`.`teacherlogs`(teacher_id,student_year,class,student_id) values (OLD.teacher_id,year_,class_,student_id_);
    ELSE
         CASE WHEN (NEW.student_year <=> OLD.student_year) = 0
         THEN update `teacherlogs` set student_year = NEW.student_year where student_id=OLD.student_id and teacher_id = OLD.teacher_id;
         WHEN (NEW.class <=> OLD.class) = 0
         THEN update `teacherlogs` set class = NEW.class where student_id=OLD.student_id and teacher_id = OLD.teacher_id
         ELSE select @dummy  END 

    end if;
END
```

But i am getting an exception at end if.

is that correct way to solve my problem or any other ways can we do?

Comment: A `CASE` **statement** needs to end with `END CASE;`, not just `END`

Comment: I find it inconceivable that a teachers table would have a student_id in it. After that, nothing makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your syntax error is that your `CASE` statement needs to end in `END CASE;`, not just `END`.

I don't think that the `CASE` statement actually works for your requirements though as if `NEW.student_year <=> OLD.student_year` then `NEW.class` will not get compared against `OLD.class` to see if that value also needs to be updated. That is because (from the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html)):

> For the second syntax, each WHEN clause search_condition expression is
>   evaluated until one is true, at which point its corresponding THEN
>   clause statement_list executes

You can get around that by just replacing the `ELSE CASE ...` with an `ELSEIF` clause:

```
ELSEIF NEW.student_year <=> OLD.student_year OR NEW.class <=> OLD.class THEN
UPDATE teacherlogs
  SET student_year = NEW.student_year, class = NEW.class 
  WHERE student_id = OLD.student_id AND teacher_id = OLD.teacher_id;
```

This should work because (based on my understanding from your question of how your database is configured) the value of `student_year` and `class` in `teacherlogs` should be the same as `OLD.student_year` and `OLD.class` and if they are the same as `NEW.student_year` and `NEW.class` the values won't get updated.

If my understanding is incorrect, you will need modify the update to have conditions on each value:

```
ELSE
    UPDATE teacherlogs
    SET student_year = IF(NEW.student_year <=> OLD.student_year, NEW.student_year, student_year),
    class = IF(NEW.class <=> OLD.class, NEW.class, class)
    -- repeat for all columns
    WHERE student_id = OLD.student_id AND teacher_id = OLD.teacher_id;
END IF;
```

Comment: Thank You @Nick ,yes if i update teachers table with two columns its not updating all two columns in teacherslogs table by using case statement.

Comment: here ,else if is good if we have  less columns,for example purpose i have taken two columns only,but i have around 10 columns,need to listen for the event among 10 columns updated ,means if one column updated means we need to update one column,if 3 columns updated means we need to update 3 columns .Is it possible to do like that instead of updating all columns ,update only whatever fields updated

Comment: If the values haven't changed then having them in the update query won't affect their value. So it should be OK to have them all in there. So you can just expand the IF expression to include all the columns.

Comment: I've updated my answer in case the `ELSEIF` solution does not work. Unfortunately it is ugly...

Comment: Thank you @Nick ,second case is  ugly, i do choose elseif and need to check is there any optimization way is tthere or not.Once again thank you for your valuable time and quick response :) .

Comment: I've updated my answer again, while I was out feeding my cows (seriously!) it occurred to me that it didn't need to be that complicated. So you might want to use that after all. If this has answered your question, it would be great if you could mark it accepted.

Comment: Is this working? If not could you give me some more info to help you solve the problem?

Comment: facing error like 'unexpected SET' after the first set statement  comma(,)

Comment: Sorry about that the `SET` should only be on the first line. I've edited my answer.

Comment: That's great. It took a while but I'm glad we got there in the end.